# NSScanner scanString: intoString: not working in playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to make a swift version of my xml parser for som weather data:

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation

let string2: NSString? = "cdefg jajaja <time> bbb"

let scanner = NSScanner(string: string2)
scanner.string
let searchString:NSString? = "<time"
var result: NSString?  = nil //= AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSString?>

scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = nil
scanner.scanString(searchString, intoString: nil) // this is not working (false)

scanner.scanUpToString( ">", intoString: &result) // this is working

result // result = "cdefg jajaja <time"
```

Why is "scanner.scanString(searchString, intoString: nil)" returning nil?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, your problem has nothing to do with Swift (equivalent Objective-C code does the same) – you're just using `NSScanner` wrong. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanString%3aintoString%3a) for `scanString:intoString:`

> Return Value
>
> YES if string matches the characters at the scan location, otherwise NO.

Basically, `scanString:intoString:` either finds `searchString` at the current position (in your example, at the start), or it returns `false`. Since your String starts with `"cdefg"` and not with `"<time"`, the method returns `false` and does not advance the scanning position. If you remove `"cdefg jajaja "` from your String, your `scanString:intoString:` call will return `true` and advance the scanning position so that the next character is `">"`. Alternatively, you could change the `scanString:intoString:` call to `scanUpToString:intoString:` to simply discard anything before and including `"<time"`.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not thank you before, but I will inform you that you solved the problem